# What is the correct way to include css, js and image files into the template with Kohana?

Tags: php, kohana

With Kohana, using a Templating system, what is the correct way to link to the style sheets, javascript files and most importantly images?

Shall I add `<?php echo url::base() ?>` in front of links? This surely does work but doesn't seem like the correct way to do things.

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Put the assets in your `DOCROOT` somewhere: `DOCROOT/assets/images/`
2. Use any of the following:

   - `url::base().'assets/images/thing.png`
   - `url::site('assets/images/thing.png')`
   - `<base href="<?=url::base()?>` (then use normal relative links in your html)

Comment: Which one of these is the most correct way in the long run you reckon? Thanks!

Comment: They all work equally well :)

I personally use the <base href> tag so simply all my html.